# Linker and Kernel Woes

Tags: x86, linker, g++, kernel, osdev

So I've hit the wall after four days. I'm working with the OSDev tut and have searched high and low for two days. I've tried everything. First I realized stupid me I was attempting 64 compilation and that's why I got a "..relocation truncated to fit: rva32 against..". I moved onto Cygwin 32 and now I'm unable to see the main in my kernel.

Sorry if it's stupid, I'm trying to work on this in between classes and I'm burnt

boot.asm compiled with >>> nasm -f elf boot.asm -o boot.o

```
MBALIGN     equ  1<<0                   ; align loaded modules on page boundaries
MEMINFO     equ  1<<1                   ; provide memory map
FLAGS       equ  MBALIGN | MEMINFO      ; this is the Multiboot 'flag' field
MAGIC       equ  0x1BADB002             ; 'magic number' lets bootloader find the header
CHECKSUM    equ -(MAGIC + FLAGS)        ; checksum of above, to prove we are multiboot

section .multiboot
align 4
    dd MAGIC
    dd FLAGS
    dd CHECKSUM

section .bootstrap_stack
align 4
stack_bottom:
times 16384 db 0
stack_top:

section .text
global _start
_start:

    mov esp, stack_top

    call kernel_main

    cli
.hang:
    hlt
    jmp .hang
```

kernel compiled with >>> g++ -c kernel.cpp -o kernel.o -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/* Hardware text mode color constants. */
enum vga_color
{
    COLOR_BLACK = 0,
    COLOR_BLUE = 1,
    COLOR_GREEN = 2,
    COLOR_CYAN = 3,
    COLOR_RED = 4,
    COLOR_MAGENTA = 5,
    COLOR_BROWN = 6,
    COLOR_LIGHT_GREY = 7,
    COLOR_DARK_GREY = 8,
    COLOR_LIGHT_BLUE = 9,
    COLOR_LIGHT_GREEN = 10,
    COLOR_LIGHT_CYAN = 11,
    COLOR_LIGHT_RED = 12,
    COLOR_LIGHT_MAGENTA = 13,
    COLOR_LIGHT_BROWN = 14,
    COLOR_WHITE = 15,
};

uint8_t make_color(enum vga_color fg, enum vga_color bg)
{
    return fg | bg << 4;
}

uint16_t make_vgaentry(char c, uint8_t color)
{
    uint16_t c16 = c;
    uint16_t color16 = color;
    return c16 | color16 << 8;
}

size_t strlen(const char* str)
{
    size_t ret = 0;
    while ( str[ret] != 0 )
        ret++;
    return ret;
}

static const size_t VGA_WIDTH = 80;
static const size_t VGA_HEIGHT = 24;

size_t terminal_row;
size_t terminal_column;
uint8_t terminal_color;
uint16_t* terminal_buffer;

void terminal_initialize()
{
    terminal_row = 0;
    terminal_column = 0;
    terminal_color = make_color(COLOR_LIGHT_GREY, COLOR_BLACK);
    terminal_buffer = (uint16_t*) 0xB8000;
    for ( size_t y = 0; y < VGA_HEIGHT; y++ )
    {
        for ( size_t x = 0; x < VGA_WIDTH; x++ )
        {
            const size_t index = y * VGA_WIDTH + x;
            terminal_buffer[index] = make_vgaentry(' ', terminal_color);
        }
    }
}

void terminal_setcolor(uint8_t color)
{
    terminal_color = color;
}

void terminal_putentryat(char c, uint8_t color, size_t x, size_t y)
{
    const size_t index = y * VGA_WIDTH + x;
    terminal_buffer[index] = make_vgaentry(c, color);
}

void terminal_putchar(char c)
{
    terminal_putentryat(c, terminal_color, terminal_column, terminal_row);
    if ( ++terminal_column == VGA_WIDTH )
    {
        terminal_column = 0;
        if ( ++terminal_row == VGA_HEIGHT )
        {
            terminal_row = 0;
        }
    }
}

void terminal_writestring(const char* data)
{
    size_t datalen = strlen(data);
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < datalen; i++ )
        terminal_putchar(data[i]);
}

extern "C"
{
    void kernel_main()
    {
        terminal_initialize();
        /* Since there is no support for newlines in terminal_putchar yet, \n will
           produce some VGA specific character instead. This is normal. */
        terminal_writestring("Hello, kernel World!\n");
    }
}
```

linker call >>> g++ -T linker.ld -o myos.bin -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib -fno-exceptions boot.o kernel.o -lgcc

```
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
    /* Begin @ 1 MB*/
    . = 1M;

    /* multiboot header -> text */
    .text BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.multiboot)
        *(.text)
    }

    /* Read only data */
    .rodata BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.rodata)
    }

    /* Read-write data */
    .data BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.data)
    }

    /* Read, write, and stack */
    .bss BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(COMMON)
        *(.bss)
        *(.bootstrap_stack)
    }

    /* Additional Here */
}
```

Maybe I'm just burnt and am not seeing something simple, but that's why I'm here

Answer (score 2):

I am aware this question is an older one, but there are a few things to learn from the problems encountered. Assuming 32 bit compilation, there are a few issues, and likely one gotchya that could have caused your problems.

When linking you have specified that the *.bootstrap_stack* will be placed in the *.bss* section:

```
.bss BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
{
    *(COMMON)
    *(.bss)
    *(.bootstrap_stack)
}
```

In `boot.asm` you define the stack with:

```
section .bootstrap_stack
align 4
stack_bottom:
    times 16384 db 0
stack_top:
```

This is fine, but you should not attempt to put initialized data into *.bss*, and the section you do add should have the `nobits`, `alloc`, and `write` attributes set to be compatible with a typical *BSS* segment. It could look something like:

```
section .bootstrap_stack nobits alloc write
align 4
stack_bottom:
    resb 16384          ; Reserves but doesn't initialize 16384 bytes
stack_top:
```

Making these changes will set up a proper stack (16k in size) in the *BSS* segment, and avoid assembler and linker warnings.

In your `boot.asm` you do `call kernel_main`. This is fine, but since it isn't inside `boot.asm` you should tell the assembler(*NASM*) that it is an external label. At the top of `boot.asm` you should add:

```
extern kernel_main
```

The biggest potential problem using *GCC* is that it will place a 4k section with `.note.gnu.build-id` after your ELF headers. This will almost guarantee that your `section .multiboot` will be placed beyond the 8k point of your ELF binary and will cause a multiboot loader (like GRUB) to tell you it can't find a multiboot header in your file. To get around this you need to link your final kernel binary (`myos.bin`) with the linker option `-Wl,--build-id=none` . You should also explicitly tell *NASM* to generate a 32 bit *ELF* object with `-f elf32` and *GCC* with `-m32` options. Your compile and link commands would look something like:

```
nasm -f elf32 boot.asm -o boot.o
g++ -m32 -c kernel.cpp -o kernel.o -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti
g++ -m32  -Wl,--build-id=none -T linker.ld -o myos.bin -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib -fno-exceptions boot.o kernel.o -lgcc
```

To compile and link with debug symbols, you could do this:

```
nasm -f elf32 -g -F dwarf boot.asm -o boot.o
g++ -g -m32  -c kernel.cpp -o kernel.o -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti
g++ -g -m32  -Wl,--build-id=none -T linker.ld -o myos.bin -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib -fno-exceptions boot.o kernel.o -lgcc
```

You should also heed the [advice](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) of OSDev Wiki to build with a cross compiler, rather than a native compiler tailored to your host environment. In the long term this could avoid some hard to find bugs.

A revised `boot.asm` could look like:

```
extern kernel_main

MBALIGN     equ  1<<0                   ; align loaded modules on page boundaries
MEMINFO     equ  1<<1                   ; provide memory map
FLAGS       equ  MBALIGN | MEMINFO      ; this is the Multiboot 'flag' field
MAGIC       equ  0x1BADB002             ; 'magic number' lets bootloader find the header
CHECKSUM    equ -(MAGIC + FLAGS)        ; checksum of above, to prove we are multiboot

section .multiboot
align 4
    dd MAGIC
    dd FLAGS
    dd CHECKSUM

section .bootstrap_stack nobits alloc write
align 4
stack_bottom:
    resb 16384               ; Reserves but doesn't initialize 16384 bytes
stack_top:

section .text
global _start
_start:

    mov esp, stack_top

    call kernel_main

    cli
.hang:
    hlt
    jmp .hang
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, GCC adds the so-called 'startup-files' to your object file, making it unable to boot up. To disable them, append `-nostartfiles` to the argument list of `g++`. Also, C++ requires a bunch of other stuff created in order for it to even boot!

Please see:
http://wiki.osdev.org/C++